# Elements Fall Outside the Viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I was using Google's PageSpeed Insights to analyze my web page. The report I got is [here](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.romancestuck.com%2Fpickup-lines.htm)

I am confused about the "Size content to viewport" in the "User Experience Beta" Section. It says things like the following:

```
<h2>Pick Up Lines Categories</h2>
```

and

```
<a href="http://www.rom…ckup-lines.htm">Bad Pick Up Lines</a>
```

are outside the viewport? I have looked at them on an iPhone and they look fine. I don't understand why they would be showing as outside the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

It's saying your page is too wide for mobile resolutions, allowing the user to scroll horizontally which decreases the user experience.

**EDIT**

This is caused mainly by `<div id="ad_footer_1_position">`, but `<div id="footer">` is also too wide for the page.

Comment: I don't understand.

<h2>Pick Up Lines Categories</h2>

is not in <div id="footer">.

Comment: Understand it or not, this will fix your issue. Maybe that's why this is still in beta by google?

Comment: At the top of my page I have a 320x100 header ad and at the bottom of the page I have a 320x100 footer ad. So, I don't understand how <div id="footer"> can be outside the viewport. Is there a reason or is it just because this part of Google Page Speed is still in beta testing?

Comment: Inspect your source code - one of the widgets you use in the footer is at least 400px wide.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.romancestuck.com/pickup-lines.htm on an iPhone? The 2 things that are the widest look to be the 2 Google ads which are each 320 pixels wide. I have display:none on the sections that look to be too wide for the iPhone.

Comment: Nope, I was looking at it in Chrome at a browser width of 320px.